# Django alias for static file path

Tags: python, django, django-4.1

I have a Django 4.1 project and want to make an alias to the directory with static files. So, in `settings.py` I have

```py
STATIC_URL = "static/"
```

All my static files are in the `example.com/static/...`. I want to make a shortcut to one of directories of static files. For example `example.com/magic/...` should be the same as `example.com/static/physics/...`. That **shoudn't be a redirect**, because if it is a redirect, I won't be able to download file using `curl` without any special options.

How can I do this? Maybe with some special paths in `urls.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the static url to

```
STATIC_URL = "http://example.com/static/"
```

Making shortcuts do directories/redirecting without a redirect like that is better done with a server like Nginx.
Example config for nginx:

```
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      80;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name localhost; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    location /static{
        proxy_pass http://example.com/static;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /magic{
        proxy_pass http://example.com/static/physics;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }


    # Finally, send all non-static requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080; # This will be your production server. Please do not use django's built in runserver.
    }

}
```

This will basically pass-through the requests in nginx, straight to the domain (example.com), this way, the redirect happens in the backend, and the user (or curl in your case) won't notice a thing. It doesn't involve the slow python interpreter, nginx is made straight in C.

If you go the nginx route, `https://django-server-example.com/static/` is the static url, not `https://example.com/static/`, it will be run on the same domain, but it will (again), pass through the requests. So `https://django-server-example.com/static/` will lead to `https://example.com/static/` (without a redirect).

If you do nginx, set the static url to `STATIC_URL = "/static/"`

So remember, django does not handle your staticfiles anymore. But still do set the `STATIC_URL`, this way your `{% static %}` templatetag works.